# Returning home to France with less than 6 months on British passport and French post-Brexit residency card

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, uk-citizens, french-residents

I am a British Citizen living in France, I hold a French EU-Article 50 (Brexit) residency permit.

Is there any risk that I'd be stopped when returning to France from the UK on my British passport because it has less than six months' validity? I'd obviously present my French residency permit too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Timatic](https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/),

> Residents of France may enter using travel documents which are valid
> on arrival.

This applies to holder of resident visa. For normal visa, the passport must be valid for 3 months from the date of departure.

See also: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-france

> If you have rights under the Withdrawal Agreement, you can enter and
> exit EU countries with a valid passport. You do not need any
> additional validity on the passport beyond the dates on which you are
> travelling.

tl;dr - You can enter with passport which is valid for less than 3 months, provided you have the resident visa.

Comment: See also [Living in France](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-france) “If you have rights under the Withdrawal Agreement, you can enter and exit EU countries with a valid passport. You do not need any additional validity on the passport beyond the dates on which you are travelling.“

Comment: Added in the answer.

Comment: This probably should be on meta but somehow we need to indicate "Living in France" links to a government site so people can know the quote is solid info. For all I know, "Living in France" could be a blog title. I usually leave the gov.uk URL visible for this reason.